# Count query with large amount of objects

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using parse.com to populate a listview in android. Each item in the list view has a textview that shows the like count and another one that shows the comment count.

Now, according to parse.com

"For classes with over 1000 objects, count operations are limited by timeouts. They may routinely yield timeout errors or return results that are only approximately correct. Thus, it is preferable to architect your application to avoid this sort of count operation."

what would be the recommended/ideal way of going about it then?

Answer (score 0):

What I did is I created a column called commentCount, and a column called likeCount. Then in `afterSave`, I modified the appropriate cell.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Activity", function(request) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); //bypasses ACL requirements

    //After commenting, increment commentCount
    if(request.object.get("type") == "comment"){
        query = new Parse.Query("Posts");
        query.get(request.object.get("post").id, {
            success: function(post) {
                post.increment("commentCount", 1);
                post.save();
            },
                error: function(error) {
                console.error("Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, can you post the code so i can get a better view. i would really appreciate it. I was able to do the like count easily but the comment cunt is giving me a head ache.

Comment: Added an example for you. @user123859

Comment: It's CloudCode, cross platform. It's automatically called after you save an object of type `Activity` in this example.

Comment: When i do this in my code it gives a lot of errors. first error is that Parse.Cloud does not exist

Comment: I know, you don't write it in your code. It goes in the Parse Cloud. Read [this](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide).

Comment: ok thanks i will get started on this and see if it works out for me if it does i will  mark answer correct

Comment: isn't it `post.increment("commentCount", 1);` atomic? this doesn't require a lock on the cell or something with dirty cells I guess.

Comment: I didn't realize that. I've had counters set to incorrect values when calling incremement at the same time and now I'm not sure why. @knshn